# Communicating between a datagridview and a windows form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that shows data from a mysql database. I also have a form that is shows this same information but this form uses a binding navigator to display each record. I would like that when i double click a row in the datagridview, the binding navigator form with the relevant row is shown. I saw some code online which passes an argument into the constructor of the form but this has not worked for me, here is what I have so far on the datagridview form.

```
if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
        { 
            DataGridViewRow r = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
            Add_Edit ae = new Add_Edit(r);
            ae.Show();
        }
```

And this on this binding navigator form

```
private DataGridViewRow row;    
    public Add_Edit(DataGridViewRow row)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.row = row;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass the DataGridViewRow to the other form, because it should not know that you are using a DataGridView (but that is an advanced programming topic). Use the object that is bound to the DataGridViewRow instead.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    object item = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    Add_Edit ae = new Add_Edit(item);
    ae.Show();
}
```

Change Add_Edit's constructor parameter to type object, because DataBoundItem will return one, and assign it to the BindingSource used to fill up your navigator. Because you cannot set the SelectedItem directly, you must get BindingSource's index for that item and set it's Position property.

```
public Add_Edit(object item) {
    InitializeComponent();

    bindingSource1.Position = bindingSource1.IndexOf(item);
}
```